# React onclick function produces increments state instead of changing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, material-ui, state

I am trying to implement a function that sets a property of the state, "changedMarkup" on a button click event.

**Constructor**

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
      changedMarkup: 0
    };
  }
```

**Render**

```
render() {
const { classes } = this.props;

return (
  <Paper className={styles.root}>
    <Tabs
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      variant="fullWidth"
      indicatorColor="primary"
      textColor="primary"
      aria-label="icon label tabs example"
    >
      <Tab onClick={() => this.changeMarkup(0)} icon={<TrendingUpIcon />} label="TRENDING" />
      <Tab onClick={() => this.changeMarkup(1)} icon={<ScheduleIcon />} label="NEW" />
      <Tab onClick={() => this.changeMarkup(2)} icon={<WhatshotIcon />} label="HOT" />
    </Tabs>
  </Paper>
);
```

}

**changeMarkup function**

```
changeMarkup = (markup) => {
    this.setState({
      changedMarkup: markup
    })
    console.log("markup", this.state.changedMarkup);
  }
```

**Expected behavior**

Log statement when the first tab is clicked: **markup 0**

Log statement when the second tab is clicked: **markup 1**

Log statement when the third tab is clicked: **markup 2**

**Resulting behaviour**

The "changeMarkup" property produces unexpected values. I can't seem to find an exact common pattern but it seems to be increment from 0 to 2 and decrements back to 0 with continuous clicks irrespective of the tab clicked

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

setState is an async operation, it won't be complete at the time you do your console logging. You can supply a callback after it has been updated:

```
this.setState({changedMarkup: markup}, () => { 
  // Do your logging here!
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this.setState({}) is async operation so if you want updated value log than you can do it in two ways.

```
  1. use callback function like this

this.setState({
    //set your state 
}, () => {
    console.log('your updated state value')
})


2. in render function like this

render(){
    console.log('your state')

    return()
}
```